# Understanding joins with an example

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I've been trying to fully understand joins with the following example I have constructed in SQL server

```
DECLARE @tablePlace TABLE (ID INT, someplace varchar(10))
DECLARE @tableType TABLE (ID INT, sometype varchar(10))
DECLARE @tableOrders TABLE (ID INT, type int , place int)

INSERT INTO @tablePlace (ID, someplace) values (1,'Place A')
INSERT INTO @tablePlace (ID, someplace) values (2,'Place B')

INSERT INTO @tableType (ID, sometype) VALUES (1,'Type 1')
INSERT INTO @tableType (ID, sometype) VALUES (2,'Type 2')
INSERT INTO @tableType (ID, sometype) VALUES (3,'Type 3')
INSERT INTO @tableType (ID, sometype) VALUES (4,'Type 4')

INSERT INTO @tableOrders (ID, place, type) values (1 , 1 , 1)  -- PLACE A TYPE 1
INSERT INTO @tableOrders (ID, place, type) values (2 , 1 , 2)  -- PLACE A TYPE 2
INSERT INTO @tableOrders (ID, place, type) values (3 , 2 , 2)  -- PLACE B TYPE 2
```

Now what I am trying to do is link the three tables to get the following result

```
╔═════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║  PLACE  ║  TYPE  ║ COUNT ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ PLACE A ║ TYPE 1 ║     1 ║
║ PLACE A ║ TYPE 2 ║     1 ║
║ PLACE A ║ TYPE 3 ║     0 ║
║ PLACE A ║ TYPE 4 ║     0 ║
║ PLACE B ║ TYPE 1 ║     0 ║
║ PLACE B ║ TYPE 2 ║     1 ║
║ PLACE B ║ TYPE 3 ║     0 ║
║ PLACE B ║ TYPE 4 ║     0 ║
╚═════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

So what I am trying to do is link the two places and show the count of each type according to the records retrieved from the `@tableorders` table.

---

My query so far:

```
SELECT place.someplace,
       type.sometype,
       Count(*) AS count
FROM   @tableOrders orders
       INNER JOIN @tableplace place
               ON orders.place = place.id
       INNER JOIN @tabletype type
               ON place.id = type.id
GROUP  BY someplace,
          sometype
ORDER  BY someplace,
          sometype
```

Could someone please explain the logic I should follow to achieve my desired results? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a *cross join* to generate the rows.  Then `left join` (or correlated subquery) to get get the value:

```
select p.someplace, t.sometype, count(o.id) as count
from @tableplace p cross join
     @tabletype t left join
     @tableOrders o
     on o.type = t.id and o.place = p.id 
group by p.someplace, t.sometype
order by p.someplace, t.sometype;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT place.someplace, [type].sometype , T.cnt
FROM @tablePlace place
CROSS join @tabletype [type] 
OUTER APPLY 
(   SELECT COUNT(1) cnt
    FROM @tableOrders tableOrders 
    WHERE tableOrders.place=place.ID AND tableOrders.[type] = [type].ID
)T
ORDER BY someplace,sometype
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Place A Type 1  1
Place A Type 2  1
Place A Type 3  0
Place A Type 4  0
Place B Type 1  0
Place B Type 2  1
Place B Type 3  0
Place B Type 4  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CROSS JOIN` for generating MxN table (connecting all places with types) and then `LEFT JOIN` to orders table to get the count for each pair `(someplace, sometype)`:

```
select tp.someplace, tt.sometype, count(to.id) as count
from @tablePlace tp
cross join @tableType tt
left join @tableOrders to on 
  to.place = tp.id and to.type = tt.id
group by tp.someplace, tt.sometype
order by tp.someplace, tt.sometype
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.someplace,B.sometype,COUNT(C.ID) count_val FROM @tablePlace A CROSS JOIN 
@tableType B LEFT JOIN @tableOrders C ON C.place = A.ID AND C.type = B.ID 
GROUP BY someplace,sometype
```

Hope it helps. :)